# Vertical Align in WPF TextBox

Tags: wpf, textbox, font-size

I have 2 `TextBox`es in my wpf app, one for user name and other for password, both have `FontSize=20`, but the text appears like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Xaml:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Text="test" />
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Password="test" />
```

Comment: What font are you using? It may be due to that.

Comment: I did not specify any, but I think it's defaulted to "Segoe UI", but I changed it but it stays the same

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Adjust the `Padding` properties of these controls, e.g. `Padding="0"`:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Text="test" Padding="0" />  
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Password="test" Padding="0" />
```

Or, don't set the `Height` properties, and instead let the controls size themselves automatically based on the height of their content:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Text="test" />
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" FontSize="36" Password="test" />
```

Answer (score 170):

To vertically center the text in a `TextBox` use the `VerticalContentAlignment` property:

```
<TextBox Text="The text" Height="40" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: or `VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;`

Answer (score 2):

You have given explicit `Height` set to `40` to these `TextBox` controls.

Please remove it and let them take enough space to show their content.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5"
            FontSize="36"
            Text="test" />
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5"
                FontSize="36"
                Password="test" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you have specified the **FontSize** property as well as the **Height** explicitly. The text with the bigger FontSize cannot fit in the given height.
So, there are a couple of solutions for this

1. Increase the Height of the TextBox to 60 (but this will create a heighted TextBox which may not look good in the UI). Or, you can just skip Height property, so that it will automatically take the minimum space it needs.

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             BorderThickness="1" 
             BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" 
             FontSize="36" 
             Text="test" />
```

2. Reduce FontSize, so that the text can fit in the TextBox with Height 40

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Height="40"
             BorderThickness="1" 
             BorderBrush="#FFD5D5D5" 
             FontSize="24" 
             Text="test" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` in your textbox